# Border in Floating Action Buttons

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm creating a app with Floating action buttons for social.

and i'm having border on FAB. see:

[image]

How to remove this border?

Comment: Slightly off topic, but you should only have one FAB on a screen. https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just have the black `f` as a separate drawable, and set that as the source of the FAB. Otherwise, if you want to use the drawable that already has a circular shaped background, don't use a FAB at all, just put it in an `ImageButton`, with a transparent background:

```
android:background="#0000"
app:srcCompat="@mipmap/action_fb"
```

Answer (score 2):

set this peoperty to your `FloatingActionButton`.

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

add this to parent.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: Error in "app" - Namespace 'app' is not on bound